# controller action not found on production server

Tags: php, zend-framework

In my development area (wamp) everything works fine. Today I uploaded my whole project to my production webspace.

I seems like in the production area, some paths are lost.
First I saw that in my start layout (ZEND_Layout) my pictures aren't found. So I needed to change the paths to the pictures in:

```
../public/images/xyz.png
```

After my loginform I change my layout and there I left the path as it was before and it works:

```
./images/xyz.png
```

This looks quite strange. I started to test my application. After the login my redirector works fine and I can see my records. With click on details (Termine) I got the next problem, here is the code snippet:

```
<td class="row_<?PHP echo $i % 2;?>">
    <a href="<?php echo $this->url(array('controller'=>'aktermine', 'action'=>'index', 'kopfnr'=>$kopf->kopfnr));?>">Termine</a>
</td>
```

I get a blank page. It seems my controller action couldn't be found.

Can anyone help solve my problem?

EDIT:

Aha, I switched my logging on and get the error:

> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_OBJECT_OPERATOR in
>   /mnt/weba/b3/45/5543245/htdocs/cheyenne/application/controllers/AktermineController.php
>   on line 88

Line 88 in the given controller is some datecast:

```
$datum = (new DateTime($form->getValue('datum')))->format('Y-m-d');
```

So that doesn´t work on the production system, but why?

EDIT 2:

I tried to change to:

```
$datum = $form->getValue('datum');
```

This works, but I need the cast, or some datepicker I asked for in another post.

Comment: Could you debug ? activating zend logs, or adding file_put_contents in zend classes where it stops ? Or if it doen't even go into Zend classes ?

Comment: Zend Framework doesn't show you syntax errors so you need to turn on php error reporting on in your index.php.

Comment: I haven´t debugged yet, so what to do exactly? I don´t think that the problem is with the classes because after the login I have an urlcall $this->_redirect('/arbeitskalender/index'); that works.

Comment: Show the whole code ? Do you use $this in class object ?

Comment: Turn display_errors on in your php.ini file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

since your are using zend framework why don't you use the [Zend_Date](http://framework.zend.com/manual/1.12/en/zend.date.creation.html)

```
$dateObj = new Zend_Date();
$dateObj->set($form->getValue('datum'),'dd/MM/yyyy');
$datum = $dateObj->toString('yyyy-MM-dd');
```

Answer (score 0):

problem was this line:

```
$datum = (new DateTime($form->getValue('datum')))->format('Y-m-d');
```

I changed it like shown above.